# When using Meteor, should I prefix npm with meteor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, npm

When working on Meteor 1.3 projects, should I always prefix `npm` with `meteor`? In the [Meteor documentation](https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html#installing-npm) and in code examples I see [both](https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html#npm-shrinkpack).

I suspect that I always want to do this:

```
$ meteor npm install --save some-package
```

But is there ever a situation, in a Meteor project, where I want to just use the system npm?

```
$ npm install --save some-package
```

Are [people just using shorthand](https://themeteorchef.com/base/packages-included/) when they omit the `meteor` prefix?

Answer (score 1):

Well, to be exact, it depends on what you want to perform.

The easy rationale is based on what Tom did not explicitely say in his answer:

- `$ meteor npm install …` will use the local `npm` shipped / bundled with Meteor Tools. It is the official supported version for Meteor.
- `$ npm install …` will use your global `npm`, which version might differ from Meteor's one.

In the case of `npm`, the difference might be unnoticeable.

Unfortunately, the situation is different for Node: Meteor 1.3 still relies on Node **0.10.43**! Simply give a try with commands `$ meteor node --version` and `$ node --version`.

Meteor 1.4 is supposed to upgrade to Node 4.

Knowing that, you can still use `$ node` (without `meteor` prefix), as long as your script does not need to be executed later on by Meteor itself (typically through a build process). Even if it does, you should not have troubles if your script does not use advanced Node features (i.e. introduced after version 0.10.43).

Answer (score 0):

At least there is no difference in using a global npm or the meteor encapsulated. For me, I always use `meteor npm` or `meteor node` because I do not need and do not want to install global software.

Also to know, the bundled node is always the release with best tested compatibility and so I always use that. Also on production environment, we have installed meteor and use the bundled npm and node when running our apps. No issues by now.

I also like to have all project related stuff inside the project folder and not globally. That means, that we do not install anything npm related globally but always local to the node-modules folder.

This gives us the opportunity to move and run our software on different self hosting environments without headages or compatibility issues even between projects with different releases on same system.

Be aware that before release 1.3.4.3 the meteor tool does not respect always latest tools but this is solved by now.

Cheers
Tom